# How to skip duplicate headers in multiple CSV files having indetical columns and merge as one big data frame

Tags: pandas

I have copied 34 CSV files having identical columns in google colab and trying to merge as one big data frame. However, each CSV has a duplicate header which needs to be skipped.

The actual header anyway will be skipped while concatenating, as my CSV files having identical columns correct?

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(path.join('/content/drive/My Drive/',x)skiprows=1) for x in os.listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/') if path.isfile(path.join('/content/drive/My Drive/',x))]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Above code throwing below error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Below code working for sample files,but need an efficient way to skip dup headers and merged into one data frame.Please suggest.

```
df1=pd.read_csv("./Aug_0816.csv",skiprows=1)
df2=pd.read_csv("./Sep_0916.csv",skiprows=1)
df3=pd.read_csv("./Oct_1016.csv",skiprows=1)
df4=pd.read_csv("./Nov_1116.csv",skiprows=1)
df5=pd.read_csv("./Dec_1216.csv",skiprows=1)
dfs=[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
df=pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `glob` from the standard library?

Try this

```
path = ('/content/drive/My Drive/')
os.chdir(path)

allFiles = glob.glob("*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f,header=None,error_bad_lines=False) for f in allFiles]
#or if you know the specific delimiter for your csv 
#dfs = [pd.read_csv(f,header=None,delimiter='yourdelimiter') for f in allFiles]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: does your code skips the dup headers? just tried with your code getting the `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 20 fields in line 20657, saw 35'.Looks dup header causing the issue?

Comment: @Optimizer you'll need to add the `skiprows = [1]` parameter to Datanovice's code as well.

Comment: I don't think it's the dupe headers, it might be that your csv's arent all the same size. when you `print(allFiles)` does it only list the csvs you want to merge ? you can also pass `headers=None`

Comment: @Datanovice, no there are dupe headers something like below. I tried with your code by adding skiprows=[1] and getting the tokenizing error. 

`
Zone State Depot Pincode Store Code Store Language
Zone State Depot Pincode Store Code Store Language
`
`
path=('/content/drive/My Drive/Nippon Data/')
os.chdir(path)

allFiles = glob.glob("*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f,skiprows=[1]) for f in allFiles]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 20 fields in line 41539, saw 34
`

Comment: @Datanovice it worked and skipped a bunch of error records with unorder line numbers, how to check what exactly error is?` Ex:b'Skipping line 41539: expected 20 fields, saw 34"`

Comment: from what I understand you have a csv in your list that has some errors in it or doesn't match your files, I guess you have 20 columns ? but one of the records has 34.what you need to do is find that pesky CSV and see why it's different. Don't forget to green tick if the answer gave you your desired result : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the most generic script for concatenating multiple 'n' csv files in a specific path with a common file name format!

```
def get_merged_csv(flist, **kwargs):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,**kwargs) for f in flist], ignore_index=True)

path = r"C:\Users\Jyotsna\Documents"
fmask = os.path.join(path, 'Detail**.csv')

df = get_merged_csv(glob.glob(fmask), index_col=None)
df.head()
```

If you want to skip some fixed rows and/or columns in each of the files before concatenating, edit the code accordingly on this line!

```
return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=4,usecols=range(9),**kwargs) for f in flist], ignore_index=True)
```